How can I use my computer's GPU on Jupyter notebook?
How can I use my GPU on Jupyter notebook?I use Anaconda and launch Jupyter notebook from there. It always say "False" when checking with torch.
I already have Cuda toolkit and CuDnn installed on my system. (https://i.sstatic.net/tnftteyf.png)
I checked by code: "import torch
torch.cuda.is_available()" It is saying False. I am unable to configure the gpu.

This question is similar to: How to make Jupyter Notebook to run on GPU?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This is a pytorch problem, not something related to jupyter notebook, and not related to tensorflow either.
